# How to change AppointmentStatus in managed Exchange Web Services

Tags: c#, exchange-server-2007, exchangewebservices

I need to change appointment status to meeting, so that it invitations can be send by one click. But `Appointment.AppointmentStatus` and `Appointment.IsMeeeting` are read only properties. I've found, using reflector, that `PropertyBag` class is used for setting and getting items properties, but it's also internal. Can I change this properties somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I manage to do it. Steps are not so simple and logical, but here they are:

```
var extendedProperty = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(new Guid("00062002-0000-0000-C000-000000000046"), 0x8217, MapiPropertyType.Integer);
meeting.SetExtendedProperty(extendedProperty, 1);
```

where Guid is PropertySet of appointments, and that strange number is MeetingStatus property id. And that's all. "Send" button is active by default.